# Rendering Firebase Data in Table Editable (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I found a tutorial on the Internet.

A simple CRUD Application written in JavaScript and React JS using Googles Realtimedatabase.

This is the Tutorial, I am talking about: https://sebhastian.com/react-firebase-real-time-database-guide

It works fine; however, it uses `<li>` elements to display the data.

My dataset is quite bigger so I would like to display the data in a table.

It works and the Table displays everything like I want to, but the edit function is broken.

In the console is logged:

> name: undefined

Here is the corresponding code. I've tried almost everything, googled, and changed the code a million times:

```
     <table class="table" id="example-table">

      <thead class="text-primary">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">PLZ</th>
          <th scope="col">Addresse</th>
          <th scope="col">Stadt</th>
          <th scope="col">lat</th>
          <th scope="col">lng</th>
          <th scope="col">Kategorie</th>

          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Ändern</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


        {developers.map(developer => (
                <tr
                  key={developer.uid}>
                <td> {developer.name}</td>
           <td> {developer.postal}</td>
          <td> {developer.address} </td>
          <td> {developer.city} </td>
          <td> {developer.lat} </td>
          <td> {developer.lng} </td>
          <td> {developer.category} </td>

                <td>  
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.removeData(developer)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.updateData(developer)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              ))}

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

EDIT:

Here is the full code.

```
import React from "react";

import Firebase from "firebase";
import config from "./config";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Firebase.initializeApp(config);

    this.state = {
      developers: []
    };
  }




  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState !== this.state) {
      this.writeUserData();
    }
  }

  writeUserData = () => {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(this.state);
    console.log("DATA SAVED");
  };

  getUserData = () => {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref("/");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(state);
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = this.refs.name.value;
    let postal = this.refs.postal.value;
    let uid = this.refs.uid.value;
    let address = this.refs.address.value;
    let city = this.refs.city.value;
    let lat = this.refs.lat.value;
    let lng = this.refs.lng.value;



    if (uid && name && postal && address && city && lat && lng) {
      const { developers } = this.state;
      const devIndex = developers.findIndex(data => {
        return data.uid === uid;
      });
      developers[devIndex].name = name;
      developers[devIndex].address = address;
      developers[devIndex].postal = postal;
      developers[devIndex].city = city;
      developers[devIndex].lat = lat;
      developers[devIndex].lng = lng;



      this.setState({ developers });
    } else if (name && postal && address && city && lat && lng) {
      const uid = new Date().getTime().toString();
      const { developers } = this.state;
      developers.push({ uid, name, postal, address, city, lat, lng });
      this.setState({ developers });
    }

    this.refs.name.value = "";
    this.refs.postal.value = "";
    this.refs.uid.value = "";
    this.refs.address.value = "";
    this.refs.city.value = "";
    this.refs.lat.value = "";
    this.refs.lng.value = "";

  };

  removeData = developer => {
    const { developers } = this.state;
    const newState = developers.filter(data => {
      return data.uid !== developer.uid;
    });
    this.setState({ developers: newState });
  };

  updateData = developer => {
    this.refs.uid.value = developer.uid;
    this.refs.name.value = developer.name;
    this.refs.postal.value = developer.postal;
    this.refs.address.value = developer.address;
    this.refs.city.value = developer.city;
    this.refs.lat.value = developer.lat;
    this.refs.lng.value = developer.lng;


  };

  render() {
    const { developers } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    Händlersuche
  </title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.3.0" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.5/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper ">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="green">

      <div class="logo">
        <a  class="simple-text logo-mini">

        </a>
        <a class="simple-text logo-normal">
          <img src="https://www.al-ko.com/shop/skin/frontend/alko_rb/default/images/logo.png"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="./dashboard.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons design_app"></i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./icons.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons education_atom"></i>
              <p>Icons</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./map.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons location_map-big"></i>
              <p>Maps</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./notifications.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></i>
              <p>Notifications</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./user.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
              <p>User Profile</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="active ">
            <a href="./tables.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons design_bullet-list-67"></i>
              <p>Table List</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./typography.html">
              <i class="now-ui-icons text_caps-small"></i>
              <p>Typography</p>
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel" id="main-panel">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent  bg-primary  navbar-absolute">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-toggle">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#pablo">Table List</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
            <form>
              <div class="input-group no-border">
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_zoom-bold"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pablo">
                  <i class="now-ui-icons media-2_sound-wave"></i>
                  <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Stats</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="now-ui-icons location_world"></i>
                  <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Some Actions</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pablo">
                  <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
                  <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Account</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="panel-header panel-header-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
              <h2>Neuen Daten Satz hinzufügen</h2>
              </div>

              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-row">
                  <input type="hidden" ref="uid" />
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="name"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Name"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>PLZ</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="postal"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="PLZ"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="address"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Address"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Stadt</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="city"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Stadt"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Laengengrad</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="lat"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Laengengrad"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Breitengrad</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="lng"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Breitengrad"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                  Speichern
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>

          <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">

                  <table class="table" id="example-table">

      <thead class="text-primary">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">PLZ</th>
          <th scope="col">Addresse</th>
          <th scope="col">Stadt</th>
          <th scope="col">lat</th>
          <th scope="col">lng</th>
          <th scope="col">Kategorie</th>

          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Ändern</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


        {developers.map(developer => (
                <tr
                  key={developer.uid}>
                <td> {developer.name}</td>
           <td> {developer.postal}</td>
          <td> {developer.address} </td>
          <td> {developer.city} </td>
          <td> {developer.lat} </td>
          <td> {developer.lng} </td>
          <td> {developer.category} </td>

                <td>  
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.removeData(developer)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.updateData(developer)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              ))}

    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>


      <footer class="footer">

      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>




</body>







      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough sample code here to know for sure... Whenever I've done something like this, the onClick handlers are usually called passing just an ID - in your case, `developer.uid` - rather than passing the whole developer object. Sounds like the error is being generated from your `updateData()` handler. We'd really need to see that bit of code to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i provided the whole code now

Comment: Hi Elias, I built this app using your code. I had to guess at the database layout, but I got it to work with some sample data...sort of. I didn't ever get a console error regarding name being undefined, but when I deleted a developer's name property directly in the database using the Firebase console, the form then displayed "undefined" for the name when I tried to edit that developer. I was able to re-enter a name, submit the form and it successfully wrote it in the database. Are you able to check the integrity of your developers data in the database? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much @MurrayR you were absolutly right. The Problem were my data not the code... when you add the data through the form it works out fine... Really appreciate your effort many many thanks